# How to make a Symbol Chracter into a float

Tags: python-3.x, character, symbols, break

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make my program 'break' when the @ symbol is inputed by the user.

I had to create a simple calculator where the user Inputs a Number, an operator and a Second number.

I already have that running.

I just can't figure out how I'm suppose to make my program stop once the '@' symbol is inputed by the user whenever thay are asked to input information.

```
num1 = float(input("Enter First Number: "))
operator = input("Enter Operator: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number: "))


while True:
    if num1 == float(["@"]):
        break
    if operator == "+":
        print("Result:" ,num1 ,operator, num2, "=" , num1+num2 )

    elif operator == "-":
        print("Result: " ,num1 ,operator, num2, "=" ,num1-num2)

    elif operator == "/":
        if num2 == 0 :
            print("Second Number Cannot Be A ZERO")
        else: print("Result: " ,num1 ,operator, num2, "=" ,num1/num2)

    elif operator =="**":
        print("Result: ", num1, operator, num2, "=", num1 ** num2)

    elif operator == "%":
        if num2 == 0 :
            print("Second Number Cannot Be A ZERO")
        print("Result: " ,num1 ,operator, num2, "=" ,num1%num2)

    elif operator == "*":
        print("Result: " ,num1 ,operator, num2, "=" ,num1*num2)

    else:
        print("Invaid Operator")
print("Thank you for playing this Simple Calculator designed by Joss")
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through this I would make a few tweaks, instead of while True, use a variable that equals True so you can change that to False upon the bad entry and break the loop.

```
kill = True  
while kill:  
    if operator = '\@' 
        kill = False
    elif operator = '+':  
        add....
```

If you are not only looking for @ character and others, you can make an array of all the function operators such as `operand = ['+','\-','/','**']` etc and have the first `if` say something along the lines of

```
kill = True  
while kill:  
    if operator not in operand: 
        kill = False
    elif operator = '+':  
        add....
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I modified your code is that it checks once a first number is inputted to see if it is a number or not. If it is, no problem. If it isn't, it converts it to a string to be checked later on.

```
    num1 = input("Enter First Number: ")
if num1 != "@":
    num1 = float(num1)
else:
    num1 = str(num1)
```

like that. then you just check for the "@" symbol later on:

```
while True:
  if num1 == "@":
    break
```

one last thing: you should move all of your code into the while loop so after it does a calculation it will ask again (if that's the intent) because right now it loops just the printing of the answer.